# chargeitpro signature url not working

Tags: javascript, php

[image]I have integrated Chargeitpro payment integrator in my application.

The payment is working good , but the signature url from chargeitpro response is not working for me.

Here is my Response only to get signature url.

```
AccountCardType:""
AccountEntryMethod:""
AccountExpiryDate:""
AmountBalance:0
AmountBill:0
AmountFee:0
AmountProcessed:0
ApprovalNumberResult:""
AvsResponseCode:""
AvsResponseText:""
BatchNumber:""
BillingName:""
CvvResponseCode:""
CvvResponseText:""
MaskedAccount:""
ProcessId:"55f5887d33aa780790c87abf"
ResultMessage:""
ResultStatus:"true"

SignatureURL:"http://easyintegratorapi.chargeitpro.com/signature.ashx?ID=55f5887d33aa780790c87abf"

TransactionType:"RequestSignature"

UniqueTransId:"285c6dfb949141158cb8514fd9f27945"
```

When i hit "http://easyintegratorapi.chargeitpro.com/signature.ashx?ID=55f5887d33aa780790c87abf" in browser , it says "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: Please help on this.

Comment: Yes. This is the issue and it is not working for me either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been resolved by ChargeItPro.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for update. i will also contact to ChargeItPro. It is genuine issue which all are facing.